# Extending owlCarousel

Tags: jquery

I have got a JS file that contains custom options for lots of owlCarousels.
I would like to set the **Right-to-Left** lanugage default setting to be

> rtl: true

for all my carousels, 
[see:](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/rtl.html)

How do I accomplish this without calling all the other options again, that I already have setup in my JS file.

Not sure if extending is the right term here. I am sure the answer is super simple, but I am very new to jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried just specifying `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ rtl:true });`?

Comment: I have. But it only works when including all other custom settings as well, which is exactly what I would like to avoid.